# Populate HTML Label with JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML page where I am trying to populate a label with a JavaScript variable

```
<html>
<body onload="loading();">
      <div>
          <h4>Main Page</h4>
          <label id="cookie1" style="color: #0026ff"/> 
<!--MORE CODE-->
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript function is shown below. It will not populate the label on the html page but if I change the label to a textfield it will work (but i want a label). I have also used 'innerhtml' which does populate the label but it ONLY shows this label.  I have more fields and buttons that are erased or hidden if i use 'innerhtml'. Is there something I am missing?

```
function loading() {
    var val1 = "Site:   " + getCookie("storeSite");
    document.getElementById("cookie1").value = val1;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting the value. Try to set the innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("cookie1").innerHTML = val1;
```

[A similar JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5mn6S/2/)

Comment: To clarify: `value` is a commonly-used property in <input> tags. But, most other element types just have an innerHTML property, as well as `innerText/textContent` depending on the browser.

Comment: ya, i did use innerhtml but it still wouldnt work. My issue was that i was going <label /> instead of <label></label>. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This line in your function

```
document.getElementById("cookie1").value = val1;
```

Should have been

```
 document.getElementById("cookie1").innerHTML = val1;
```